# React Native/ Expo issue sending app URL to phone or email. Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: javascript, react-native, proxy, ssl-certificate, expo

Running this on a work computer (probably something with network?)

I just DL Visual Studio Code for first time, had to set up the proxy/https proxy. Was able to download node/npm successfully. Ran a create-react-native-app script of 'npm start' it seems to have bundled correctly and is now running.

When I try to send the URL that it is running on through text or email, I get an error:

```
Could not send link. Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I'm unsure how to move forward. If I can solve this myself, that would be amazing.

Thank you